# Problems parsing heroku.yml - build.web is a forbidden property

Tags: git, docker, heroku

When I push to `heroku master` I get following error:

```
=!= There were problems parsing your heroku.yml. We've detected the following issues:
remote:
remote: "build" must validate one and only one schema (oneOf). Found none valid
remote:
remote: build.web in body is a forbidden property
remote:
remote: build.docker in body is a forbidden property
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to radiant-crag-94686.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/radiant-crag-94686.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/radiant-crag-94686.git'
```

My `heroku.yml` is this and looks like on the Heroku dev center:

```
setup:
  addons:
  - plan: heroku-postgresql
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile
release:
  image: web
  command:
    - python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
run:
  web: gunicorn bookstore_project.wsgi
```

I  tried deleting the app and creating a new one, still the the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Can you double-check the indentation on your `heroku.yml` file? I had the error `.web in body is a forbidden property` and fixed it by indenting the web property below `run`. I'd check the same for the docker property. I'm not sure about the other errors though.